# World of Warcraft - poor performance

Tags: wine

First, i havent used linux for 4-6 years. Im pretty noob to all the new stuff.
I have latest ubuntu, with all the updates. And 1.4 wine.
I have pre-installed WoW, on my windows partition. Im trying to run it with Wine, but the performance is really poor, and im low on colors. Also getting graphic errors ingame.
Im using integrated GPU HD4000 (I5 3570k)

Is any tweaking required, or do i have to install drivers..? Everything else is running well on the GPU (youtube, movies etc..)

Answer (score 1):

As a PC gamer and Ubuntu enthusiast, I have run into many issues getting games to run in ubuntu. While wine is good, its definitely not perfect. I would recommend updating your system first, you can do this by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

next, check for restricted drivers:

1. Go to System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers
2. Once the drivers are downloaded and installed, reboot your computer.

once all that is done, next lets switch to Unity 2D, this will take some load off your system:

This gif explains how:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VghyR.gif

just locate the Ubuntu logo above next to your name at login, and select 2D

As long as I have been using ubuntu, gaming has been a challenge to say the least. Valve is gearing up to release Steam on Linux, and ID Software said there next game engine is built with Windows, MAC, and Linux in mind. until then, just keep tweaking! good luck!